# How do I get the name of a table without it printing the table: 0xwhatever thing?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am making a thing where that logs functions (for now) and am planning to make a thing code easier to read. And in order for it to work completely I need it to show the name of the table instead of showing the table thing.

```lua
export = {} -- for exporting data
functiontable = {} -- for exporting raw functions  (code that was run)
-- Function Replacing
oldprint = print
function log(funcname, funccontent, rawfunction)
    e = #export+1
    oldprint(funcname .. "  " .. funccontent .. "  " .. "export".."["..e.."]") -- prints the input automatically
    export[e] = funcname .."  "..tostring(funccontent) .."  "..  "export".." ["..e.."]" -- saving data in a table
    functiontable[#functiontable+1] = rawfunction
end
function print(content)
    if content == nil then
        content = "Nothing entered"
    end
    oldprint(content)
    funccontent = content
    if type(funccontent) == "string" then
        funccontent = "\""..funccontent.."\""
    end
    log("print", content, "print".."  ("..funccontent..")")
end
```

This is my code and basically what it does is take functions that were run and simplifies them and also shows what function is run with what paramaters
For example

`print("hi")` would look like this

> print hi export[1]

(function, paramaters, location of where it is logged)

and for the raw function I want it to show

`print("hi")` which it does until I try to use tables

for the data

if I would do `print(export[1])` it would print

> print hi export[1]

which is what I want but the issue I have is for the function it says it is this
`print("print hi export[1]")`
when the actual code is
`print(export[1])`

I don't know how to fix this and I also want to add table logging but for that it prints that weird 0x thing and I want the name. The example output I want is

> table tablename export[whatever]

what I get is

> table 0xsomething export[whatever]

Comment: Tables don't have names, so no, you can't

Comment: in `a = {}` , `a` is not the name of the table, it's a reference to that table. `a=b`, now you have two references to that table, which one would you consider its name then?